# SQLiteDialect_pysqlite cannot be used as a data source for security reasons

Tags: apache-superset

I've a error in the middle of using superset database. I've gotten add new database from my local storage, but I've got a error as follow in screenshot.

How can I solve this?

[image]

Comment: SQLiteDialect_pysqlite cannot be used as a data source for security reasons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Support for SQLite database connections was retired via configuration some versions ago due to security reasons (basically, it's not a proper DB to support multi-web servers).

That said, if your superset set up is simple and the SQLite DB isn't going to support heavy workload, you can turn support on by changing the config file (I haven't checked if it's still possible for the latest versions, I've done it for some versions ago, check the official superset documentation to see if this method is still valid).

Edit the config.py file and change `PREVENT_UNSAFE_DB_CONNECTIONS = False`.

Comment: It's just odd that the standard docker image contains an out-of-the box examples database (SQLite) which fails to load because of this setting.

Comment: https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/9748#issuecomment-1124323169