# Superset sqlite3 connection

Tags: sqlite

How can I connect superset hosted on docker to local sqlite3?

I was trying to connect to sqlite3 from superset, I gave sqlalchemy url as "sqlite:///test.db". Its throwing below error: "An error occurred while creating databases: (sqlalchemy_uri) SQLiteDialect_pysqlite cannot be used as a data source for security reasons."

Answer (score 0):

See: [SQLiteDialect_pysqlite cannot be used as a data source for security reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73005725/sqlitedialect-pysqlite-cannot-be-used-as-a-data-source-for-security-reasons)

Superset is dropping support for SQLite, so you need to add `PREVENT_UNSAFE_DB_CONNECTIONS = False` to `config.py`